# overloading in different programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, overloading

Can somebody please explain (with example) the difference between context-independent and context-dependent overloading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never heard about those. And there's only about five hits on Google, one of which is this very question, which seems to suggest to me that these are made-up terms. And as with any made-up term, if you want to know what it means, you have to ask the person who made it up.

From what little I could gather, it seems to be related to return-type based overloading.

Basically, if you have four overloaded functions like these:

```
foo :: string → int
foo :: string → string
foo :: string → ()
foo :: int → int
```

And you call them like this:

```
1 + foo 1
1 + foo "one"
foo "one"
```

Then, with context-dependent overloading (i.e. overloading based on the return type as well as the parameter types), the following implementations will be selected:

```
1 + foo 1     # foo :: int → int
1 + foo "one" # foo :: string → int (because `+` takes an `int`)
foo "one"     # foo :: string → ()  (because there is no return value)
```

Whereas with context-independent overloading (i.e. ignoring the return type), the following implementations will be selected:

```
1 + foo 1     # foo :: int → int
1 + foo "one" # ERROR
foo "one"     # ERROR
```

In both the `ERROR` cases, there is an ambiguity between `foo :: string → int`, `foo :: string → string` and `foo :: string → ()`, since they only differ in their return type but have the same paremeter type.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [here](http://www.cs.jcu.edu.au/Subjects/cp2003/1998/ch7Type/typeSystems.html):

> There are two kinds of overloading of
>   functions/operators.
>
> - context-independent - overloading only done on parameters to
>     function or type of operands for an
>     operator
> - context-dependent - which abstraction to call also depends upon
>     the type of the result